# Connection could not be established with host sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io:stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tsl://sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io:587

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, mailtrap

Connection could not be established with host sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tsl://sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io:587 (Unable to find the socket transport "tsl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?)

Why does it always show an error like this, even though I've changed the port to 465, 587, and 2525, and also switched the encryption from SSL to TLS

env.

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=8a0bd323485d04
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tsl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=fiorezaradhinn@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="milenialstuff.id"
```

config/mail.php

```
<?php

    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],

        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => env('MAIL_SENDMAIL_PATH', '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i'),
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],

        'failover' => [
            'transport' => 'failover',
            'mailers' => [
                'smtp',
                'log',
            ],
        'stream' => [
            'ssl' => [
                'allow_self_signed' => true,
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                ],
            ]
        ],
    ],
```

email view

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('css', '/css/email.css')
@section('title','Reset Password')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="judul">
                    <p>{{ ('Reset Password') }}</p>
                </div>
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('password.email') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="row mb-3">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Email Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="buttonsubmit">
                                    {{ __('Send Password Reset Link') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

reset view

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Reset Password') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('password.update') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">

                        <div class="row mb-3">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Email Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ $email ?? old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row mb-3">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row mb-3">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Reset Password') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I want to test sending an email to a user using Mailtrap.

Comment: Try adding smtp.gmail.com to your MAIL_HOST..it is the host for the gmail...hope it helps you

Comment: Try set "MAIL_ENCRYPTION" as null.
I only set "MAIL_ENCRYPTION" as null and the mailtrap can work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please note that the name of the encryption should be "tls" instead of "tsl". In your configuration, update the line `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tsl` to `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls`.

Here's the corrected version of your configuration:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=8a0bd323485d04
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=fiorezaradhinn@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="milenialstuff.id"
```